# preg_grep failing to capture with a valid regex

Tags: php, regex

Given the array of strings in the form

```
$log_files = Array("access_log.201401231215.txt", 
                   "access_log.201401231230.txt", 
                   "old_format_access_log.201401231200.txt");
```

I want to put into an array all of the strings that are in a given format (eg, `"access_log.*TIMESTAMP*.txt"`) but the preg_grep is not working.

```
$file_format_to_capture = "access_log"

$re = "^" . $file_format_to_capture  . ".*?$";

$matched_files = preg_grep($re, $log_files);
```

In my netbeans console I can see `$re` is set to `"^access_log.*?$"`, [which seems correct](http://regex101.com/r/hG5vX6). I would expect to capture the first two elements of the `$log_files` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [add delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
$re = "/^" . $file_format_to_capture  . ".*?$/";
```

You can also use `~regex~` or `#regex#` in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Regexes need delimiters. Personally I like to use parentheses, because they come in matching pairs (therefore they don't require anything in the pattern to be escaped "just because" it's the same symbol), and it also serves as a reminder that index `0` of matches corresponds to the whole match.

So:

```
$re = "(^".preg_quote($file_format_to_capture).")";
```

I've also used [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote) to cover edge cases where you might have a significant character in your file format (most notably `.`), and `.*?$` is unnecessary so I removed it.

Comment: PHP doesn't mention parenthesis delimitation anywhere in [their documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), so I wouldn't rely on it.  But good note on `preg_quote()`.

Comment: @SamSullivan So [this part](http://prntscr.com/2s6dae) isn't written in plain English?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't realize brackets included parenthesis. I thought they included: `[]`, `{}`, and `〈〉`. Good to know :)